# python vlc.py or vlcwidget.py unable to open the MRL

Tags: python, vlc

I am encountering the following error. The mpg file is in the same directory where vlcwidget.py is located.  Could some one point it out the issue or share thier experience?

```
C:\workspace\python-HEAD\python>vlcwidget.py trn_anaglyph_adj.mpg
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 4.1.4
libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.10 for DVD access
libdvdread: Can't stat trn_anaglyph_adj.mpg
No such file or directory
libdvdread: Could not open trn_anaglyph_adj.mpg
libdvdnav: vm: failed to open/read the DVD
[01bbd45c] filesystem access error: cannot open file trn_anaglyph_adj.mpg (No su
ch file or directory)
[01bbd45c] main access error: File reading failed
[01bbd45c] main access error: VLC could not open the file "trn_anaglyph_adj.mpg"
.
[0095fd8c] main input error: open of `trn_anaglyph_adj.mpg' failed: (null)
[0095fd8c] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[0095fd8c] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'trn_anaglyph_adj.mpg
'. Check the log for details.

C:\workspace\python-HEAD\python>vlcwidget.py trn_anaglyph_adj.mpg
```

Answer (score 0):

use full path? (maybe libvlc is running from wherever libvlc.dll is located or what not)...